# How can I gain access to my code? I can't get into Apps Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I keep getting the following error messages when I try to invoke the script editor:

> Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again.

I tried closing all Gmail accounts. I closed the browser (Google Chrome) and rebooted the computer - started Chrome browser - started GMail for required account.

But still no access to my code. Expect App script editor to open.

I'm open to any suggests.

Comment: Have you tried going to https://script.google.com/home/ and opening up the project from there.

Comment: Welcome. I think that your question is getting down votes because it's not clear what you are asking and because the title isn't a summary of the question as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem by clearing cache